# why can't I type \rf to start R in vim after install the Vim-R-plugin?

Tags: r, vim-plugin, vim-r

I install the vim-r-plugin and at the last step followed this:

Start Vim again and edit an R script. Type `<LocalLeader>rf` to start R and run
the command below to get help configuring ~/.Rprofile, ~/.vimrc, ~/.tmux.conf,
and ~/.bashrc (the `<LocalLeader>` is \ by default).

however, at the normal mode nowhere I can type in "\rf". I typed in ':\rf' but that's totally wrong with this message"E10: \ should be followed by /,? or &". Does anyone know what's the reason?

Comment: You question is mostly meaningless to this R user but I will observe that in regex patterns within R you do need to double and sometimes even triple backslashes because "\" is the R escape character. Have you tried "\\rf"?

Comment: are you sure \ is your leader key? Check with `:let mapleader` or `:let maplocalleader`. If I recall, vim-r might add a line to your .vimrc that sets it to , (comma).

Answer (score 1):

you must type \rf quickly, even hold pressing \ while r then f keys.